# Not receiving notification email from Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I've got [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/) setup on my website with [Notifications](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/email-notifications) turned on.  I've filled in the `to` and `from` address to send emails to my Gmail Account. But when someone fills out the form, I don't get the notification email.  Does the webserver require email to be turned on? Is there some other setting I should check?

Answer (score 1):

The notification e-mails are most likely in your "*Updates*" Gmail tab

The Google official [help for Tabs and Category Labels](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016) says that the Update tab will take "*Notifications such as confirmations, receipts, bills, and statements.*", which seems to be the case.

Comment: At the very least, check your spam bucket.